# Why class constructor dont work when object initialization by copy?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why class object's constructor doesnt work when I initialize it with a copy of another object?

```
class Human
{
   int No;
   public:
       Human(int arg):No(arg)
       {
        cout<<"constructor Works"<<endl;
       }
};
int main()
{
    Human a{10}; // constructor Works for object a
    Human b{a};  //why b object's constructor dont work?
}
```

Comment: you have no copy constructor

Comment: What do you mean by "dont work"?

Comment: Ah OK, you are using the *copy constructor*, which works but doesn't print anything to stdout.

Comment: Is this kind of like "why doesn't this line multiply? `auto x = y / j;`?

Comment: Ah, sorry, that's not the problem. Yours is a very basic misunderstanding. Stroustrup's misconception applies only to *aggregate* classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By "doesn't work" do you mean there was no output to the screen after running the code? Well of course there wasn't - `Human b{a}` calls a completely different constructor from `Human a{10}`. It calls the compiler-generated *copy-constructor*, which is signed as:

```
Human(Human const& other)
```

If you want there to be output upon copy construction, just create your own:

```
class Human
{
    // ...
    Human(Human const& other)
        : No{other.No}
    {
        std::cout << "copy-constructor\n";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 8):

You need a copy constructor, otherwise the compiler will generate one (which does not output anything). Add:

```
Human(const Human& h):No(h.No) { std::cout << "copy-ctor" << std::endl; }
```

Comment: Now waiting for incoming "I have a copy-constr but it looks like the compiler isn't calling it, is this a bug?"

Comment: @GManNickG Why? The OPs type is not an aggregate type, is it?

Comment: @GManNickG But you *know* it is a bug! I swear it is!!

Comment: @DanielFrey: Compilers are allowed to elide calling copy constructors under some scenarios, even if it changes the behavior of the program. Aggregate or not, one should never rely on a copy-constuctor having any behavior other than modifying the object.

Comment: @GManNickG Ah, that's what you meant. Well, this might indeed be an upcoming question. But let's not forget that we all once were newbies :)